# plotly: fix the position of text which aligned to the gauge in Indicator

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have below code, whenever I zoom in or zoom out the position of the text which is in the middle of the gauge is changing. How to align fix the position of text with gauge.
Is there way to fix the position of the text .

````
from dash import Dash,html,dcc,Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from base64 import b64encode
import io

app = Dash(__name__)

buffer = io.StringIO()

val = 45
title = 'Max'
```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Indicator(
        domain = {'x':[ 0,1],'y':[0,1] },
        title = {
            'text':title,
            'font_size':40
        },
        value = val,
        number = {
            'font_size':50
        },
        mode = 'gauge + number ', # delta
        
        gauge= {'shape':'angular','steps':[
                {'range':[    0,30],'color': 'green'},
                {'range': [30,60],color': 'yellow'},
                { 'range':[60,80],   'color':'red'}],
            'bar':{
                'color':'black',
                'thickness':0.5
            },
            # 'tickmode' : 'linear', # it is wrong but not found any other way
            'threshold':{
                'line':{'color':'orange',
                    'width': 8},'thickness':0.8,'value':60,},
            'axis':{'range':[0,80],'tickformat':'s' }
        }
    )
)

fig.add_annotation(
    x = 0.5,
    y = 0.4,
    text = 'More than enough',
    font = dict(
        size = 30,
        color = 'darkred'
    ),showarrow= True    
)

fig.write_html(
    buffer
)

html_bytes = buffer.getvalue().encode()
encoded = b64encode(html_bytes).decode()

app.layout = html.Div(
    [html.H2('Dashboard option'  ),dcc.Graph(id='Graph', figure = fig),
     html.A(html.Button( 'Download' ), id='download', href = 'data:text/html;base64,' + encoded,download = 'plotly_graph.html')])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```
````

the gauge is
[image]

Comment: You zoom in and out with what because there is no zooming icons in your graph?

Comment: If you introduce a coordinate standard into the text annotation and paper it over, it would be possible to change the width of the output HTML, etc. so that it would not be misaligned. `fig.add_annotation(
    x = 0.5,
    y = 0.4,
    xref='paper',
    yref='paper',...)`

Comment: @Hamzah zoom in , zoom out means when I change the size of the page then it is changing the position of the alignment..

Comment: @r-beginners. after changing xref, yref same things occur